# ie9 html select option does not display long text

Tags: html, internet-explorer, select

I have this problem with html select on ie9 (browser mode: compatablity view and doc mode: ie7 standards).

```
<select ...>
   <option title="test1">test1</option>
   <option title="test2">test2</option>
   <option title="longer text....more than 255">longer text....more than 255</option>
</select>
```

in ie7 the choices are shown and also the longer text...but in ie9 the issue is the dropdown is no longer working (it does not show the choices). it only show the first item. how can i fixed this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you two options:

1. Use add bellow attribute to you dropdownlist,even though if your complepte text is not displayed while loading the page, you can display complete message using tooltip.
   **ToolTip="your string "**
2. set width of the dropdown to its max lenght, as per my knowlge it would be 256. (but it wld nt be good,b 'cz it will reflect your GUI)

Comment: I already have the tooltip. Anyway, is this a ie9 known issue? co'z were planning to file ticket to msdn